# office.js code after context.sync not running

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm having trouble to extract values from an excel file with the office.js add in I'm writing.

The add in shall help my colleagues to prepare report sheets for each teacher. 
It is supposed to filter the corresponding courses from the master table and send the data to the next processing step (create word files for each teacher).

I've tried filtering ranges with autofilter and creating a table with the data, but it seems that no code is executed after `return context.sync()`

I've read the official tutorial and some of the code on buildingofficeaddins.com but my function never executes the code after "return context.sync()"

```
function mselectTeacher(teachers) {
  Excel.run(function (context) {
    var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var lfv = sheet.tables.add("A1:M211", true);
    var wsy = lfv.columns.getItem("WS/SS");
    var studium = lfv.columns.getItem("Studium");
    // some more colums

    wsy.load("values");
    studium.load("values");

    return context.sync()
      .then(function () {

//I actually want to filter the rows by teacher, 
//this is only for testing
        for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
          console.log(wsy[i] + "," + studium[i]);
        }
    });
  });
}
```

Is the problem, that I'm calling Excel.run from within another function?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
function mselectTeacher(teachers) {
  Excel.run(function (context) {
    var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var lfv = sheet.tables.add("A1:M211", true);
    var wsy = lfv.columns.getItem("WS/SS");
    var studium = lfv.columns.getItem("Studium");
    // some more colums

    wsy.load("values");
    studium.load("values");

   context.sync()

//I actually want to filter the rows by teacher, 
//this is only for testing
        for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
          console.log(wsy[i] + "," + studium[i]);
        }

  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. I've tried your suggestion and the console.log is executed, but the values are undefined and a rich.api error is caught, complaining that no promise object is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in [ScriptLab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab) on excel web and saw "The requested resource doesn't exist"error in F12

I think it's due to no columns named "WS/SS" "Studium" in your new added table. It works after i changed the columns name with "WS/SS" "Studium"

Comment: Thank you for your response, the workbook is actually prepared by our superior, so the worksheet is mostly filled with values and I create the table afterwards.

Comment: So are you sure there is "WS/SS" "Studium" column for table in A1:M211 ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The headers are; ["WS/SS", "Studium", "Sem.", "Gruppe", "Gruppengröße", "Modul", "Modultitel", "LV-Nummer / Funktion NEU", "LV-Titel", "LV-Typ", "Credits", "L-SWSt", "Personen-Kürzel"]

Comment: Can you try your code with [ScriptLab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab) on excel online and use F12 of browser to see if any error  in console to help diagnostic